# JSQMessages Are Being Shown Under Navigation Bar From Show Segue

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a ChatViewController that extends JSQMessagesViewController.

```
final class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {
   ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Messages"

        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = .zero
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = .zero

        automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = true

        collectionView?.reloadData()
        collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = true

        // REMOVE the attachment button for now
        self.inputToolbar.contentView?.leftBarButtonItem = nil
        self.inputToolbar.contentView?.textView?.placeHolder = "Compose a message to your driver"
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        observeMessages()
    }

    private func observeMessages() {
        messageRef = channelRef!.child("messages")
        let messageQuery = messageRef.queryLimited(toLast:25)
        newMessageRefHandle = messageQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            let messageData = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, String>
            if let id = messageData["senderId"] as String!, let name = messageData["senderName"] as String!, let text = messageData["text"] as String!, text.characters.count > 0 {
                self.addMessage(withId: id, name: name, text: text)
                self.finishReceivingMessage()
            } else {
                print("Error! Could not decode message data")
            }
        })
    }

 }
```

This view controller is called by a push segue that has a navigation controller. Within my storyboard, I have a simple segue from a bar item button that pushes to a View Controller with ChatViewController set as the custom class. Within the storyboard, the navigation bar is inferred (shown on top).

[image: messages over bar]

However, when I go into ChatViewController, the messages are shown under the navigation bar. Once I click into the message text box, the messages are correctly positioned. How do I fix this so the user does not have to click into the text box? Is there a command I'm missing that correctly lays out the new messages?

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been addressed [here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/174) and [here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/803), actually. You can simply set the top inset to account for the bar's height. Jesse Squires actually made a special member for such cases called `topContentAdditionalInset`, which you can use like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.topContentAdditionalInset = myBarsHeight   // in CGFloat
}
```

Comment: Thanks for leading me down the right path... I couldn't find that particular property for the view controller... I ended up setting the collection view content inset top to collectionView?.contentInset.top = height + 8

Comment: Setting the collectionView?.contentInset.top messed up some stuff for me, that's when I found out about that property. Glad you got it to work though! :-)